# Calculating the percentage of uniqueness

Tags: c#, .net

I've figured out how to compare 2 text boxes and count how many words are the same in each one and how many are different but I was wondering instead of showing exactly how many are the same and how many are different could I calculate the percentage of difference between them?

For those who I confused, if i wrote this entire message again under this post and changed a few words and maybe removed some I could get feedback from the program telling me the difference is 14% or so...

Comment: When you say you count how many words are the same, do you take into account, they are located in the postion within two given strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get words by using `string.Split`:

```
String[] words1 = Textbox1.Text.Split();
String[] words2 = Textbox2.Text.Split();
```

You can use Linq to compare both:

```
var sameWordsInBoth = words1.Intersect(words2);
int count1 = sameWordsInBoth.Count();
var inTxt1ButNotInTxt2 = words1.Except(words2);
int count2 = inTxt1ButNotInTxt2.Count();
var inTxt2ButNotInTxt1 = words2.Except(words1);
int count3 = inTxt2ButNotInTxt1.Count();
```

To get the percentage you just have to count the total words(f.e. `words1.Length`) and compare that to the other counts.

For example:

```
double sameWordPercentage = (1.0 * count1 / words1.Length) * 100;
```

Comment: `sameWordPercentage = (count1 / words1.Length) * 100;` will give 0. (Integer division)

Comment: @EVERYONE so what way is the right way? i thought double Percentile = (UniqueWordCount/TotalWordCount)*100; ?

Comment: @ace007: Have you seen my answer? One of the values must be double then the result is also double, therefore i've used `1.0*count1...`(1.0*count1 will convert the int to a double).

Comment: @Tim Schmelter .. german name, no? anyway it works, accepted as correct answer *gives him a frankfurter* danke :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you already have the amount of unique words, and dont need explanation on how to get them:

```
double UniqueWordCount = 71;
double TotalWordCount = 231;

double Percentile = (UniqueWordCount/TotalWordCount)*100;
```

Answer : 30.7359.... %

If you want to round it

```
Math.Round(Percentile,2)
```

Answer : 30.74 %

Comment: No the result is 0 since you are making integer division.

Comment: actualy the above results in 

Percentile = 30.735930735930733